# Getting list of hours that are not in interval

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to get a list of hours that are not in integers interval. For example if interval is 10 to 23 it should return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,24].

I have written this method.

```
List<int> GetTimeList(List<Mail> Mails, int TransferSpeed)
        {
            List<int> Hours = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 };

            foreach (Mail mail in Mails)
            {
                Hours.RemoveAll(x => x >= mail.DateAndTime.Hour && x <= GetRoundedTransferTime(TransferSpeed, mail.Size));
            }
            return Hours;
        }
```

And it actually works fine, but I am looking for more elegant and more efficient way.

I would be very grateful if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Linq's `Except`.

Like this:

```
List<int> intervals=new List<int>
{
      10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
 };

List<int> Hours = Enumerable.Range(1,24).ToList();

 var NotInIntervals=Hours.Except(intervals).ToList();

 foreach(var hour in NotInIntervals.OrderBy(x=>x))
  {
       Console.WriteLine(hour);
   }
```

**Result**

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,24
```

Comment: And `Enumerable.Range(1, 24)`. It is also technically possible that IEnuermable.Except does not return the same order (it will for Linq2Objects, as an implementation detail).

Comment: Also, can skip the intermediate build of times to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

My *first* attempt would probably look something like this.

(While this works well-enough for hours, it does not scale to an arbitrary time resolution. It also is not very suited to looking at arbitrary days.)

```
var hours = Enumerable.Range(1, 24);

// Build sequence of ranges of all start..end hours.
// I put in an extra Select to-anon for code clarity-of-intent.
// SelectMany takes returns of [10,11,12],[1,2],[11,12] eg.
// and turns them into a single sequence like [10,11,12,1,2,11,12]
var exclusions = Mails
    .Select(m => new {
       Start = m.DateAndTime.Hour,
       // Don't care if we run past > 24, although THIS MIGHT BE
       // A DEFECT IN THE ORIGINAL that should be addressed..
       Duration = GetRoundedTransferTime(TransferSpeed, m.Size),
    })
    // To address previous potential defect, build appropriate
    // sequence in here that understands how to 'wrap around' days.
    .SelectMany(s => Enumerable.Range(s.Start, s.Duration));

// All hours in day minus exclusion hours.
// (Exclusion ranges are already expressed as individual hours.)
return hours.Except(exclusions)
    .OrderBy(h => h) // technically not needed here
    .ToList();
```

Also, as a general note: prefer `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` (eg.) on return types from methods to prevent 'unexpected mutations in callers'.